# While many modern politicians obviously struggle to reach this ideal

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Bill Clinton, on occasion, described Barack Obama as “a man cool on
>   the outside, but who burns for America on the inside.” Whether you
>   believe this notion to be correct or not, this is a classical
>   description of the Stoic thinker, who removes emotion and passion from
>   his rational approach to logical thought. It also reminds us of the
>   Roman Stoics of classical times, such as Marcus Aurelius, who wrote
>   that dispassionate consideration is the best approach to the
>   challenges of life and government. **While many modern politicians
>   obviously struggle to reach this ideal, it is interesting that this
>   particular image of the perfect leader exists in the first place, in
>   the minds of politicians and the public alike**.
>
> [Stoicism a beginners guide to the history philosophy of stoicism]

1. "While many modern politicians obviously struggle to reach this ideal, it is interesting that this particular image of the perfect leader exists in the first place, in the minds of politicians and the public alike"

Why is it interesting there? Could you explain this to me?

2. "... exists in the first place, in the minds of politicians and the public alike"

What is the role of "alike" there?

Thanks

Comment: Introducing an essay by saying that something is "interesting" usually means that the author will proceed to demonstrate *why* it is interesting. This is hardly unique to English. ... *alike* is an extension of the ordinarily meaning "similar" here--that is, that the idea exists in the minds of *both* politicians and the public.

Answer (score 1):

**interesting that ... [it] exists *in the first place***

Worthy of exploration and consideration is the very fact that the ideal exists at all.

Where does the ideal exist?

The ideal exists in the minds of politicians and (exists) in the minds of the public.

To continue StoneyB's thought, **alike** there is probably best paraphrased as he did with **both** or as I do above with **and**.  **alike**  as it is used there doesn't mean that politicians and the public share similar views of the ideal. The ideal merely exists in the minds of both.